# Registering soap handler at client side using java

Tags: java, soap, axis

```
public class MySoapHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

  @Override
  public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {

    Map<String, String> prop = Client.getProperties();

    System.out.println("Client : handleMessage()......");

    Boolean isRequest = (Boolean) context
        .get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();

    // if this is a request, true for outbound messages, false for inbound

    if (isRequest) {

      try {

    }
    } 
  }
...
...

}
```

in my main class , from where i send soap request contains code to register the handler:

```
  QName portName = new QName("MySoapHandler");
  HandlerRegistry registry =
    service.getHandlerRegistry(); List handlerList = new ArrayList();
    handlerList.add(new HandlerInfo(MySoapHandler.class, null,
    null)); registry.setHandlerChain(portName, handlerList);
```

It is not working . What should i do? I have got a legacy code to work upon. I am unable to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to use WebServiceInterface.

Please refer this link for more detail : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-soap-handler-example/

Comment: I can't change server side code...I don't have access to it.....please tell me how to direct the program flow to the custom handler from client side itself

Answer (score 0):

I was able to register my client-side handler programmically using this code:

```
MyWebServicePortType myWebServicePortType
    = service.getPort(MyWebServicePortType.class);

Binding binding = ((BindingProvider)myWebServicePortType).getBinding();
List<Handler> handlerList = binding.getHandlerChain();
handlerList.add(new MySoapHandler());
binding.setHandlerChain(handlerList);
```

I found this method at

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/handlers.html#wp267318